How can I convert a Python dictionary to an XML string and back while preserving the structure exactly?
I have a need to convert some json to xml and then back to json ideally preserving the structure. I've gotten quite close but I can't find a way to use dicttoxml/xmltodict to not end up with each list of dictionaries being a dictionary with the key 'item' and the original dictionary it's value.
e.g.
{'mydicts': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'alice'}]}

becomes:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><mydicts><item><id>1</id><name>alice</name></item></mydicts></root>

ends up as:
{'mydicts': [{'item': {'id': '1', 'name': 'alice'}}]}

I had to use force_list as well originally. My last resort will be some post-processing code to make this change but I'd prefer to avoid that. Here is some sample code of what I have now:
import xmltodict
import dicttoxml

original_json = {
    "mydicts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "alice"
        }
    ]
}


xml_string = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(original_json, attr_type=False).decode()

new_json = xmltodict.parse(xml_string, xml_attribs=False, force_list={'mydicts'})['root']

print(new_json)

Other solutions are perfectly fine as well.

What xml_string prints to? May be item element is already there

It is in there, I imagine that's a requirement of conversion to xml for the 'tag'. If there is a way to avoid it there that would be fine but I don't think that's possible.

It works straight forward using xmltodict.unparse() by surrounding the original dict with a root object
import xmltodict

original_json = {
    "mydicts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "alice"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bob"
        }
    ]
}

tmp_json = {}
tmp_json['root'] = original_json

xml_string = xmltodict.unparse(tmp_json)

print(xml_string)

new_json = xmltodict.parse(xml_string, xml_attribs=False)['root']

print(new_json)

Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><mydicts><id>1</id><name>alice</name></mydicts><mydicts><id>2</id><name>bob</name></mydicts></root>
{'mydicts': [{'id': '1', 'name': 'alice'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'bob'}]}


This looks perfect, I had noticed 'unparse' today when searching but didn't expect it to solve this. Thanks!

As addition to the answer from @LMC there is also a Modul json2xml:
from json2xml import json2xml
from json2xml.utils import readfromurl, readfromstring, readfromjson

data = readfromstring('{"mydicts": [{"id": 1, "name": "alice"}]}')

print(json2xml.Json2xml(data, wrapper="all", pretty=True).to_xml())

Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<all>
    <mydicts type="list">
        <item type="dict">
            <id type="int">1</id>
            <name type="str">alice</name>
        </item>
    </mydicts>
</all>

If you don’t like the type information you can switch it off with attr_type=False.
